# how to read the nested list in csv file using pandas like a list

Tags: python, csv, pandas, scrapy, nested-lists

I have scraped the data from a site "itjuzi.com",and store nested list in csv file, and read it with pandas .But now the how to read the unicode string or nested list like a list ? and encoding ?

[image]

the code is "pd.read_csv('/root/code/company_info.csv',encoding='utf-8')"

sample of source data

"[[u'\u5b5f\u51e1\u5b87', u'\u521b\u59cb\u4eba', u'\u963f\u72fc\u5de5\u4f5c\u5ba4\u521b\u59cb\u4eba\u517cCEO', u'http://www.itjuzi.com/person/29395']]

all source data

http://7rf31y.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/company_info.csv

Comment: Do you need store data to `csv`? Or is possible for you create `DataFrame` from nested list directly?

Comment: Can you copy paste the text in the image rather than including an image in your question? Also, please include the approach you have tried. That will help users here help you.

Comment: @jezrael json file is ok too .

Comment: @PlantPark - can you add sample `json` to question instead of picture?

Comment: @Kartik ok, the text is here  [[u'\u9e64\u5e74\u5802\u4e2d\u533b\u9662']] ,[[u'\u9ad8\u6a1f\u8d44\u672c', u'\u4e2d\u56fd\...

Answer (score -1):

The unicode data is there, it's just not rendered:

```
$ print(u'[\u9e64\u5e74\u5802\u4e2d\u533b\u9662]')
[鹤年堂中医院]
```

Regarding your list of lists you need to adjust your spider code. By default scrapy ItemLoaders and even Selector's `eextract()` method returns a list of values, even if there is only one value in it.

To resolve that just make sure the values are not lists:

```
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

def parse(self, response):
    # you can use .extract_first() function
    item = dict()
    item['name'] = response.xpath('//div').extract_first()
    yield item
    # or you can use itemloader
    class MyItemLoader(scrapy.loaders.ItemLoader):
        name_out = TakeFirst()
    loader = MyItemLoader(selector=response)
    loader.add_xpath('name', '//div')
    yield loader.load_item()
```